# How can I use an env variable as a key in a object?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I have the following code. I want to set the `xxxxxx` in logins to `process.env.cognitoId`, where `congitoId` has the string I need to pass in as a key. This particular string is unique and must not be shown, how can I achieve this?

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: process.env.IdentityPoolId,
  Logins: {
    'xxxxxxxxx': val.token
  }
})
```

Comment: `[process.env.cognitoId]: val.token`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [] not string interpolation. That will allow you to set the key

Answer (score 1):

You can extract it beforehand:

```
let awsConfig = {
  IdentityPoolId: process.env.IdentityPoolId,
  Logins: {}
};

awsConfig.Logins[process.env.cognitoId] = val.token;

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(awsConfig);
```